# How to make the 9*9 map in which I can write numbers in some grids using Qt5.12.1?

Tags: qt, sudoku

I am just starting to learn Qt and I plan to write a sudoku program.
So I need to have a 9*9 map in which I can enter numbers in some grids.I have already used QPainter to draw the 9*9 map,but I can't enter the numbers in its grids.How to solve that problem?
And if I want to have a new 9*9 map with some numbers which can't be modified in it and in other grids I can enter numbers freely,what should I do?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Id go with QLineEdits as well, and then just disable the pre-set ones.

this should give you a starting point (Note: I've added a simple gridLayout to the mainWindow in this example):

```
  // 2D list of all line-edits - in case you want to access the elements later
QList<QList<QLineEdit*>> numEdits;
QValidator *validator = new QIntValidator(1, 9, this);

for (int idx = 0; idx < 9; ++idx) {
    numEdits.append(QList<QLineEdit*>());

    for (int jdx = 0; jdx < 9; ++jdx) {
        QLineEdit *item = new QLineEdit(this);
        item->setValidator(validator);

        // for pre-set values
        item->setEnabled(false);

        ui->gridLayout->addWidget(item, idx, jdx);

        numEdits[idx].append(item);
    }
}
```